# Why can't ESC key close the comment box

Tags: support, comments, keyboard-shortcuts

Isn't there a way to close the comment box if you decide to not comment again. Maybe pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key or a cancel button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is such a button; depending on your browser and OS, <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> will do the trick. Refreshing the page will close any dialogs on it.